# Python regex replace with ASCII value

Tags: python, regex, replace

My input string is something like `He#108##108#o` and the output should be `Hello`.

Basically I want to replace each `#[0-9]+#` with the relevant ASCII characters of the number inside the `##`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a replacement function in your regex, which extracts the digits, converts them to integer, and then to character:

```
import re

s = "He#108##108#o"

print(re.sub("#(\d+)#", lambda x : chr(int(x.group(1))), s))
```

Result:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `re.split()`:

```
import re

s = "He#108##108#o"

new_s = re.split("#+", s)

final_s = ''.join(chr(int(i)) if i.isdigit() else i for i in new_s)
```

Output:

```
Hello
```