# Manipulating substrings found to replace

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want the replacement to depend on what is found. ie. an example of what I'm after might be the following

```
def f(x):
    return str(int(x) + 1)

print(re.sub(r"(\d)", f(r"\1"), "123"))

#print 234
```

However, that doesn't actually work of course. Is some way of doing what I intend without having to keep track of the position/length of the found string and then replacing it on the next line? ie. I'm looking for a way to do this in one go.

---

Note the actual example I'm working on isn't as simple. I'm making a function which interprets a mathematical calculation string input.

Eg. "2 + 4 * 6 / 3"

The idea would be for the function to replace "4 * 6" with 24, then "24 / 3" with 8, and finally "2 + 8" with 10. It will search for the appropriate pairs and follow BIDMAS using regex.

Comment: regex replacement can be a function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620436/python-regex-replace-with-ascii-value/45620531?s=1|1.7344#45620531  but your evaluator may choke on parentheses and/or operator priorities.

Comment: @Rightleg yeah, looks like it, but not as simple as the original question though. thanks for the upvote if it's you :) and thanks to the upvoter if not.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah it was me ^^ Well, I'm currently (finally!) learning `re`, and I did not know of this possibility, so...

Comment: @Rightleg this is not very well-know, but super-powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's simplistic, but you could build some simple evaluator by applying regexes first on multiply, then on add operators, using a replacement function:

```
import re

s = "4 + 6 * 7"

def replfunc(m):
    a = int(m.group(1))
    b = int(m.group(3))
    op = m.group(2)
    if op=="*":
        return str(a*b)
    elif op=="+":
        return str(a+b)

for op in "*+":
    s = re.sub("(\d+)\s*({})\s*(\d+)".format(re.escape(op)),replfunc,s)
```

here, regex tries to match "number operator number" (with optional spaces in between) and calls the replacement function on match.

The replacement function acts accordignly, converting to integer, peforming the relevant operation, and returning back a string to be replaced.

Of course, this isn't designed to process parenthesized expressions and will never be, consider third-party evaluators instead, like [simpleeval](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpleeval) (searching in pypi gives dozens of results)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't the way that you are trying to do it, but have you considered using the [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function?

```
>>> statement = input("Expression: ")
3 + 4 * (5 + 2)
>>> eval(statement)
31
```

This is certainly easier than using RegEx.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Yes I've considered `eval()` but it's user input.

Comment: try `eval("__import__('os').system('clear')", {})` or `eval("__import__('os').system('clear')", {})`. The user can inject code into your system. No, don't use `eval`

Comment: eval is perfectly fine as long as you sanitize your data.

Comment: For instance something along the line of `a = input("Calculation: ")` then `if re.match(r"[^\d+\-*/^()]", a):    print("Invalid!")    else:    print(eval(a))` This would work well for your needs.